# Why in this derivation we have ${1\over{\cos y}}={1\over{(1-x^2)^{1/{2}}}}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Let $\sin^{-1}x=y$,
then $\sin y = x $ and therefore:

$$\eqalign{\cos y \,{dy\over{dx}} = 1&\Longrightarrow
{dy\over{dx}} = {1\over{\cos y}}\\
&\Longrightarrow
{dy\over{dx}}  = {1\over{(1-x^2)^{1/{2}}}}}$$

Why in this derivation we have $\displaystyle{1\over{\cos y}}={1\over{(1-x^2)^{1/{2}}}}$?

Comment: $\cos^2 y = 1 - \sin^2 y$. Now $\sin y = x$. Note that there is a tacit assumption about the range, $\cos y$ could also be negative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 

 Use the Pythagorean identity $$\cos  \;\!{y}=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2y},$$ what should be its sign based on the range of $y$ ? To finish it off use that $y=\sin^{-1}x$. Be careful with the domains and ranges!